# How do you limit retry & rescue in this Ruby example?

Tags: ruby

In the humble book of Ruby, an example of using Rescue and retry is provided of sending HTTP headers to a server using the following code:

```
def make_request
  if (@http11)
    self.send('HTTP/1.1')
  else
    self.send('HTTP/1.0')
  end
rescue ProtocolError
  @http11 = false
  retry
end
```

To limit an infinite loop in case it doesn't resolve, what code would I have to insert to cap the retries to say 5 times? Would it be something like:

```
5.times { retry }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can just write a `5.times` plus a `break` on success inside the loop, or  abstract the pattern to keep the logic separate from the looping. An idea:

```
module Kernel
  def with_rescue(exceptions, retries: 5)
    try = 0
    begin
      yield try
    rescue *exceptions => exc
      try += 1
      try <= retries ? retry : raise
    end
  end
end

with_rescue([ProtocolError], retries: 5) do |try|
  protocol = (try == 0) ? 'HTTP/1.1' : 'HTTP/1.0'
  send(protocol)
end
```

Comment: Not quite yet, but that excerpt seems simple enough. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. My main reason for asking was just to understand how, don't have an actual application to this piece of code just yet.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but the [retriable gem](https://github.com/kamui/retriable) does basically this exact thing.

Answer (score 6):

I used this function to run and retry a command a limited number of times with an intermittent delay. It turns out the `tries` argument can simply be augmented in the function body and is passed on when `retry` is called.

```
def run_and_retry_on_exception(cmd, tries: 0, max_tries: 3, delay: 10)
  tries += 1
  run_or_raise(cmd)
rescue SomeException => exception
  report_exception(exception, cmd: cmd)
  unless tries >= max_tries
    sleep delay
    retry
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could set a variable to 0 and increase it every time you retry, until your maximum is reached, like this:

```
def make_request
  limiter = 0
  ...
rescue ProtocolError
  @http11 = false
  if limiter < MAXIMUM
    retry
  end
end
```

Additionally you could try it yourself with this:

```
def make_request
  raise ProtocolError
rescue ProtocolError
  try_to_find_how_to_limit_it
end
```

Comment: I think this limiter should be limiter ||= 0, otherwise it gets reset to 0 everytime.